# How to decode this json string

Tags: json, go

My json string from the frontend of my application is

```
{"ticker":"glencore","dated":"25/5/2121","resource_name":"testing","latlong":"","type":"","measured":{"0":{"symbol":"4","grade":"4","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"48000000","contained_unit":"t"},"1":{"symbol":"1","grade":"4","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"48000000","contained_unit":"t"},"value":"5","unit":"tons"},"indicated":{"0":{"symbol":"4","grade":"1","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"10000000","contained_unit":"t"},"1":{"symbol":"1","grade":"1","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"10000000","contained_unit":"t"},"value":"4","unit":"tons"},"inferred":{"0":{"symbol":"4","grade":"2","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"18000000","contained_unit":"t"},"1":{"symbol":"1","grade":"2","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"18000000","contained_unit":"t"},"value":"3","unit":"tons"},"total":{"0":{"symbol":"4","grade":"3","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"24000000","contained_unit":"t"},"1":{"symbol":"1","grade":"3","grade_unit":"grams_per_ton","contained":"24000000","contained_unit":"t"},"value":"2","unit":"tons"}}
```

and my golang code to decode is

```
type HTTPMineral struct {
        Symbol        string `json:"symbol"`
        Grade         string `json:"grade"`
        GradeUnit     string `json:"grade_unit"`
        Contained     string `json:"contained"`
        ContainedUnit string `json:"contained_unit"`
    }
    type HTTPResource struct {
        Ticker        string        `json:"ticker"`
        ResourceName  string        `json:"resource_name"`
        DateOfRelease string        `json:"dated"`
        Measured      []HTTPMineral `json:"measured"`
        Indicated     []HTTPMineral `json:"indicated"`
        Inferred      []HTTPMineral `json:"inferred"`
        Total         []HTTPMineral `json:"total"`
    }

    resource := &HTTPResource{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(resource); err != nil {
        log.Println("unmarshaling error ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Decodedresource")
```

I keep getting the below error

```
2020/11/30 16:36:34 unmarshaling error  json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field HTTPResource.measured of type []main.HTTPMineral
Decodedresource
```

I'm sure it must be something i'm overlooking but i've been over it several times and i cant understand how my struct is incorrect.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `measured`, `indicated`, etc. fields are not arrays, they are JSON objects that are organized like arrays. Use

```
Measured map[string]HTTPMineral
```

and then get the items by using `data.Measured["0"]` instead of `data.Measured[0]`

Comment: Measured      map[string]HTTPMineral `json:"measured"`
Indicated     map[string]HTTPMineral `json:"indicated"`
Inferred      map[string]HTTPMineral `json:"inferred"`
Total         map[string]HTTPMineral `json:"total"`


When i try it like this i get 
unmarshaling error  json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field HTTPResource.measured of type main.HTTPMineral

Comment: That error means you defined `Measured` `HTTPMineral`, not  map[string]HTTPMineral

Answer (score 0):

Key Indicated, Inferred and Total are not array type they are associative array(which have key name as index).

```
  type HTTPMineral struct {
            Symbol        string `json:"symbol"`
            Grade         string `json:"grade"`
            GradeUnit     string `json:"grade_unit"`
            Contained     string `json:"contained"`
            ContainedUnit string `json:"contained_unit"`
        }
        type SHttpMineral map[string]HTTPMineral
        type PHttpMineral struct {
            IHttpMineral
            Value string `json:"value"`
            Unit  string `json:"unit"`
        }
    
        type HTTPResource struct {
            Ticker        string       `json:"ticker"`
            ResourceName  string       `json:"resource_name"`
            DateOfRelease string       `json:"dated"`
            Measured      PHttpMineral `json:"measured"`
            Indicated     PHttpMineral `json:"indicated"`
            Inferred      PHttpMineral `json:"inferred"`
            Total         PHttpMineral `json:"total"`
        }
    
        resource := &HTTPResource{}
        if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(resource); err != nil {
        log.Println("unmarshaling error ", err)
    }
fmt.Println("Decodedresource")
```